# about golang type create Specification

Tags: go

the example code

```
package main

import "fmt"

type ipoint int

type Futest struct {
    Name string
}

func main() {
    i := ipoint(1)
    fmt.Println(i) //print 1

    futest := Futest{
        Name: "test",
    }
    fmt.Println(futest) //print {test}
}
```

my question is :
why ipoint object only ipoint(1) create,but Futest struct need more complex statmenet

```
Futest{
        Name: "test",
    }
```

any [golang Specification describe it](https://go.dev/ref/spec)

Comment: It can also be `Futest{"test"}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ipoint` is a type of int and `Futest` is a type of struct. We can covert integer to `ipoint` and assign to new variable called `i` as shown below.

```golang
i := ipoint(1)
```

We can create a new instance from struct as shown below.

```golang
  futest := Futest{
        Name: "test",
  }

  // or

  futest := Futest{"test"}

  // If the struct has more than one fields,
  // We need to maintain the order of fields.
  // 
  //  Example:
  //
  //   type A struct {
  //    Number int
  //    Name string
  //   }
  // 
  //   a := A{1,"sample"}
```